# As3 Google DoubleClick Video

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I'm very frustrated with Google DoubleClick's AS3 documentation. I'm not an advanced ActionScript coder and I have limited experience with streaming video, but I feel like their API is omitting a lot of information about how these classes actually work.

I'm attempting to load an FLV to play in an expanded unit. Their video component API shows how to control playback of a video, but it doesn't say anything about how to actually load an flv file through code into the component.

http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/flash/as3/en/com_google_ads_studio_video_VideoPlayer.html

I found a controller API, but I have no idea how a "controller" works, or what it is, and the API doesn't explain anything outside of vague general information. I assume the controller needs to be somehow associated with the video player component, but there's nothing anywhere on Google that explains this in any form.

http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/flash/as3/en/com_google_ads_studio_video_VideoController.html

So, in conclusion, what I want is simple. I want to programically load an flv file into a video component on the stage, and have it play. I feel like this is a simple thing to do. I can do this with netstream objects and regular means, but Google has explained nothing in it's API on how to achieve this in studio rich media, and I have no idea how the inner workings of it's components function. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: You should contact your account manager at Google. Our's is great and we can often practically send over FLAs that we're having trouble with and they'll implement the complex parts for you.

Answer (score 0):

For using video in Studio, you use either the basic or advanced video player component, and component inspector to specify your video, then upload all your assets.

You can literally browse through hundreds of templates, including filtering for features like video, and choose one that best fits your needs along with documentaion here.

http://www.richmediagallery.com/resources/template-database

Basic video overview

https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/1719810?hl=en

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that page existed. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I could only add 2 links to my answer above

Here is the AS3 API for video

http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/flash/as3/en/com_google_ads_studio_video_VideoPlayer.html

And the one for video player advanced

http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/flash/as3/en/com_google_ads_studio_video_VideoPlayerAdvanced.html